# Python Pandas: np.searchsorted() returns wrong index value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames. One data frame (df1) has 75799 rows and other data frame (df2) has 13715 rows.

df1

```
OBJECTID    ENABLED DATECREATED        DATEMODIFIED        OWNER    STATUS  ACCURACY  INSTALLATIONDATE
 

      2            1    23/08/2001 0:00:00  3/04/2020 0:00:00   ABC In Service  Unknown     26/09/1969 0:00:00
      8            1    23/08/2001 0:00:00  3/04/2020 0:00:00   ABC In Service  Unknown     23/08/1989 0:00:00
      12           1    23/08/2001 0:00:00  3/04/2020 0:00:00   ABC In Service  Unknown     13/04/1971 0:00:00      
      19           1    23/08/2001 0:00:00  3/04/2020 0:00:00   ABC In Service  Unknown     22/03/1976 0:00:00
```

df2:

```
OBJECTID    FID_OHElectricLineSegment_2k    ENABLED   DATECREATED         DATEMODIFIED    OWNER 
1                  19                        1       23/08/2001 0:00:00 3/04/2020 0:00:00   AUR
2                  41                        1       23/08/2001 0:00:00 2/04/2020 0:00:00   AUR
3                  98                        1       23/08/2001 0:00:00 3/04/2020 0:00:00   CONS
4                  167                       1       23/08/2001 0:00:00 3/04/2020 0:00:00   CONS
```

I am comparing OBJECTID of df1 with FID_OHElectricLineSegment_2k of df2 and create a new column in df1 'zone' column and insert value of 1 if both column has the same value. Here is how I am doing:

```
df1.loc[np.searchsorted(df1['OBJECTID'].values,df2['FID_OHElectricLineSegment_2k'].values),'Zone']=1
```

however, it returns an error that

```
KeyError: '[75799] not in index'
```

I can understand that df1 has total rows of 75799 (0 to 75798), However, I could not understand how come `np.searchsorted()` returns the index value which does not exist. Could anyone help me where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `loc` to `iloc` since `np.searchsorted` return the position

```
idx=np.searchsorted(df1['OBJECTID'].values,df2['FID_OHElectricLineSegment_2k'].values)
idx=np.clip(idx,a_max=len(df)-1,a_min=0)    
df1.iloc[idx,'Zone']=1
```

Comment: I already tried that it throws 
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds message

Comment: @user2293224 the problem here due to when you have larger value than the df1, it will append to the end so the length is out of bound

Comment: Thanks for your effort. With updated code, it throws ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]. I tried to search this error but could not get it.